# App engine P12 AccessControlException

Tags: java, google-app-engine, credentials, accesscontrolexception

I am trying to read a P12 key on App Engine ( Google )
They key is located in WEB-INF directory.

Currently I have this code :

```
Credential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                .setTransport(httpTransport)
                .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
                .setServiceAccountId(ACCOUNT_ID_PROPERTY)
                .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(
                        new File("/WEB-INF/key.p12"))
                .setServiceAccountScopes(scopes).build();
```

But it's returning me this error :

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "\WEB-INF\key.p12" "read")
```

Any idea's to fix this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please remove the forward slash from the path. Provide `new File("WEB-INF/key.p12")` and it should get through.

Comment: Wow, if that solves it (and Romin you're usually right) then the original exception and its message are seriously misleading, it's actually a path does not exist error.  And then I wonder where one of us could bug report that.

Comment: Actually due to the fact that a File class is being used, it takes the absolute path and hence it gives the error. Another way to avoid this I believe is to use 
InputStream is = context.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/key.p12"); and it should be fine but I am not sure if that is the data type the method will accept. To look at current issues and file bugs : https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list

Comment: Thanks and I do submit and follow AppEngine bug reports.  What I meant to ask was whether bug reports about GoogleCredential.Builder() should go to AppEngine or elsewhere, or whether this is about File().  I second your getResourceAsStream suggestion.

Comment: I believe this is about File().

Comment: Fair enough.  Then the File exception makes sense, it's AppEngine runtime saying "nobody is allowed to do File with me!", not just a particular path.  You'd better correct your answer to use getResourceAsStream.

Comment: That parameter needs to be of File type - so I am not sure about that.