# Load resource file in Google Cloud Endpoints

Tags: google-app-engine, maven, intellij-idea, push-notification, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm using Google Cloud Endpoints as back end of a mobile application.
Now i want to implement push notifications for the iOS client but can't load the .p12 certificate from an `@ApiMethod`, get this error message:

> Invalid keystore reference.  File does not exist:
>   /base/data/home/apps/s~my-ws/1.379168523188882449/MyCert.p12"

I added the certificate under `/src` directory but does not seem to recognize it.

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA, Appengine API 1.9.12, javapns (for Push Notifications) and Maven.

**Edit**

Maybe i made a step forward.

I put the .p12 file under `/src/webapp/WEB-INF/` and added

```
<configuration>...<webResources><resource><includes><include>*.p12</include>
```

in my pom.xml.

Then i run `mvn clean install && mvn appengine:endpoints_get_discovery_doc` and inspected the generated `myws-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war`. Within the .war file there is my `MyCert.p12`certificate, but i get this error message now:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (\"java.io.FilePermission\" \"/WEB-INF/MyCert.p12\" \"read\")"
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you check the code that is actually loading the cert? [It may be that you need to remove a leading slash from the `File` constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22002782/app-engine-p12-accesscontrolexception). This is not an App Engine thing but a java `File` thing.

Also, unrelated to your solution but helpful, is a [thread here on best ways to store p12 files on App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25432619/where-to-keep-p12-file-securely-on-app-engine).